# Logic disambiguation in composed sentences with negative predicates and "or" conjunction

Tags: syntax, grammar, negation, logic, word-sense-disambiguation

Today, I've attended a psychological test for the master thesis of a friend of mine. The target is children and adults. So don't scare if you see in the following lines that I speak about animals.

I ask you a minute of patience to read fully my question.

The test is composed by two phases:

1. You see animals (on a paper) that may eat two foods, it's choosen by the examiner if the animal eat one food, two foods or none of them. If the answer is two you attach to the animal a **gold medal**, if it's one a **bronze medal**, if it's zero a **sad face**.
2. The examiner (using a frog) states a sentence and you have to say if it's **true** or **false**.The disambiguation emerges at this phase with a particular type of sentences.

Example.
In the phase 1 the hippo ate one food (a carrot) and it has a bronze medal.The frog say

> The hippo didn't eat a carrot or a cucumber.

Is it true or false? I answered that's true.
Why? Because I transformed the sentence to

> The hippo didn't eat a carrot or it didn't eat a cucumber

The first part is false but the second one is true, with an or this means true.
Anyway, it's possible another transformation

> The hippo did not ( eat a carrot or eat a cucmuber)

Which thanks to De Morgan's laws become

> The hippo did not eat a carrot and did not eat a cucumber

This is obviously false.

I transformed the sentence beacuse in my opinion conjuction like or/and "must" connect sentences, I.e "the carpet is red or heavy" is not valid, a right one may be "the carpet is red or the carpet is heavy".

Probably, you have already understood that the issue is related the negation, logic operator precedence, sentences truncation and De Morgan's laws and how the latter is felt by people (i.e. embedded in natural language).
I want to deepen in this topic and see what you expert say. In addition feel free to correct my answer and to say that I'm wrong with my test answer.

So my question are:

- What's the correct transformation to eliminate the disambiguation?
- Is it needed such a transformation to state something about this type of question?
- Does the transformation depend on language (e.g english and russian use the same transformation)?
- If no transformation is needed how do you face with this kind of sentences?does a way exist or may be only interpreted?

These articles are helping me to answer to the question:

- http://ling.uni-konstanz.de/pages/home/romero/papers/li-hanromero-final-submit.pdf
- http://mentalmodels.princeton.edu/papers/2014sentential-negation.pdf

(there is a third, but I've to wait for 10 points so it is in the comments)

Comment: Natural language is unavoidably ambiguous, so there is usually no single correct transformation. But, it may indeed be the case that speakers of different languages have different distributions for their understanding of conjunctions/disjunctions in sentences.

Comment: What you ran into is known as [De Morgan's Law](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). It says that "Not (A Or B) is Equivalent to (Not A) And (Not B)". If he is not sick and he is not absent, then he is not sick or absent. We can eliminate one ambiguity by saying _neither sick nor absent_, or in this case _did not eat a carrot nor a cucumber_.

Comment: And in English negation scopes over disjunction (but it varies in other languages, e.g., Mandarin has reverse scope), so yes, you apply De Morgan's law here.

Comment: @JeremyNeedle, thanks for your comment, I agree with you. Anyway, personally how do you interpretate the frog question?

Comment: @jlawler, thanks for your comment. I'm not doubting about De Morgan's Law. My point is more related to what to do when you have a declarative sentence with negative polarity and ellipsis. In your example you did an implication, I'm trying to get, if exists, an equivalent sentence without the ellipsis.So, do you assert that "I'm not sick or absent" means "I not (am sick or am absent)"?

Comment: @IvanKapitonov, thanks very much, you give me some terms to investigate better the topic.

Comment: the third article  http://www.nyu.edu/projects/szabolcsi/szabolcsi_haddican_conjunction_october.pdf

Comment: @Emiliano substituting words that could occur together, yes, _I am not tired or hungry_ does mean _I am not tired and I am not hungry_. The [logical form of De Morgan's Laws](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) show what happens algebraically: `¬(p ⋁ q) ≡ (¬p ⋀ ¬q)`. If you distribute `¬` (_not_) across the conjunction `⋁` (_or_) so it applies to both `p` and `q`, then you have to change the `⋁` to `⋀` (_and_). And there are two laws; the symmetric one -- `¬(p ⋀ q) ≡ (¬p ⋁ ¬q)` -- says that `⋀` also changes to  `⋁` under the same circumstances.

Comment: @jlawler, thank you for your response. My problem is the mapping between the real sentence and the formal one or pragmatically how to remove the ellipsis without modify the meaning.

You transform "I am not tired or hungry" to `¬(p ⋁ q)` where  `p ≡ I am tired` and `q ≡ I am hungry`, in other word you states that "I am not tired or hungry" is the same as "I not ( am tired or am hungry). My issue is that you implicitly add "am" in the part with "hungry", originally it doesn't appear.

Comment: @jlawler, in my ignorance, I want to understand if this addition is a rule valid always or not, damned ellipsis :) . (The De Morgan's Laws were/are very clear to me and the point isn't their validity). Consider it more a problem of language than logic.

Comment: @Emiliano _Am_ has no meaning; it is a required auxiliary verb with adjectival or noun predicates. Are you asking about the logical rule, or about English syntax? The logical rule is always valid, but only in logic. Syntax is much more complicated; still, logic can be useful. The relation of logic to syntax is like the relation of math to physics -- you can't understand the details without it.

Comment: @jlawler, thanks for the answer. What does English syntax say about this situation when the auxiliary verb is implicit in the second clause?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "implicit". Auxiliary verbs are either present, elided, or absent. They don't imply anything; they're meaningless, and exist only to mark constructions and boundaries.

Comment: @jlawler Why do you say *am* has no meaning, what about its tense?

Comment: The tense has (a little) meaning; the auxiliary that carries it has none. The tense marker goes on the first auxiliary verb, and sometimes requires one to be present; but the auxiliary verb itself is nothing but a rack with a label on it.

Comment: Thank you very much @jlawler. Your last comment is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a major difference between the natural language use (I do mean "use") of "or", "and" and the logical connectors that they traditionally translate. Whether "or" means "at least one" versus "exactly one" is a pragmatic matter, thus "Would you like pie or cake" at a dinner party is probably an offer of pie, cake, or both pie and cake. At a restaurant, the offer "For desert you can have pie or cake" probably means you have to pick one.

Your description of the experiment isn't clear enough. If it is given that the hippo has a sad face and it ate a carrot, then the proffered rule for medal-assignment is not being followed. Therefore the frog's statement is somewhat immaterial – and perhaps that is the point of the experiment. But that problem aside, your first transformation is the problem. The sentence "The hippo didn't eat a carrot or a cucumber" means "The hippo didn't (eat (a carrot or a cucumber))", so negation has scope over the two disjuncts.

Comment: Thanks @user6726, you let me discover a "typo" in my question, the hippo had a bronze medal instead of a sad face. In addition, you confirm the negation takes precedence over disjunction in the sense that negation scope cover all clauses. I am not sure that it is valid for all languages.